# Determining maximum/minimum values at which marginal effect is significant

Tags: statistical-significance, confidence-interval, marginal-effect

I am running the following regression:

```
reg stdnutrition stdlogdeficit stdinfrastructure c.stdlogdeficit#c.stdinfrastructure
```

where all variables are standardised.

I want to determine the minimum and maximum values of "stdinfrastructure" at which the marginal effect of "stdlogdeficit" on "stdnutrition" is significant.

And vice versa the minimum and maximum values of "stdlogdeficit" at which the marginal effect of "stdinfrastructure" on "stdnutrition" is significant.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.